# C++ String of Bytes convert to byte datatype and count bytes

Tags: c++, c, string, types, byte

As the title says I try to convert to byte data type a C++ String of Bytes and count bytes.
The string I get from textbox will contain a series of one byte hexadecimal numbers, but I need to send it as bytes.

```
char packet_data[200];
HWND hTextBox2 = GetDlgItem(TabOneDlg,IDC_EDIT3);

SendMessageA(hTextBox2, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)200, (LPARAM)packet_data);
```

That's how I get the input value (I am using win32 API - unmanaged forms)

EXAMPLE of input string (hex)

```
AA BB CC DD - 4 bytes !
```

In SHORT I want to do this :
Got a string containing a textual representation of hexadecimal numbers, and I want to convert each textual representation of the hexadecimal numbers to "normal" numbers.

Comment: A string of characters is simply a collection of bytes. The amount of data in the string, i.e. the amount of bytes, is returned by the [`WM_GETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't treat it as a collection of bytes but as a string. That's why I posted this here.

Comment: And the string looks like AA BB CC DD (just like hex) - so that means 4 bytes.

Comment: A string is a collection of bytes, where each byte often happen to be the same as ASCII values for characters. So just send the string "as is".

Comment: `sizeof(char) = sizeof(byte) = 1`, so yes, your buffer is a string **and** a collection of bytes.

Comment: So you mean you have string containing a _textual representation_ of hexadecimal numbers, and you want to convert each textual representation of the hexadecimal numbers to "normal" numbers?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg That's exactly what I want to do ! Can you please help me?

Comment: holy smoke batman.  you figured out what he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the hexadecimal numbers are separated by a space (as shown in the question) it is a simple question of extracting them. The simplest way in C++ is by using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and the normal input operator `>>`:

```
std::istringstream istr(packet_data);
std::vector<uint8_t> data;

uint8_t i;
while (istr >> std::hex >> i)
    data.push_back(i);
```

After the above code, the vector `data` will have all data from the string. If you need to e.g. send the data over a socket (or similar) you can use [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get a raw pointer to the data (or use `&data[0]` if the `data` function doesn't exist), and the number of bytes is available from [`std::vector::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

Comment: Well I get this error : error C2955: 'std::vector' : use of class template requires template argument list  for the std::vector::data. I can't find the source of error. Also I need to send this as a LPVOID just as this: ConstructPacket (packet_data, op_code); (That was an old example)

Comment: @thang Oops, forgot that! :)

Comment: You'll need to include `<cstdint>` for `uint8_t`.

Comment: @virusbogdan A pointer to `void` (i.e. `void *`) is a pointer that can point to anything. So a function having a `void *` (or in your case `LPVOID` which is a `#define` for `void *`) as argument can take any pointer.

Comment: I just can't seem to be able to call the std::vector::data to get the raw data. May I get an example - I might do something wrong.  The call I have to make looks like this:    ConstructPacket(OUR..VECTOR..DATA, total_size, iOpcode);

Comment: @virusbogdan The `data` function is a normal member function of `vector`, but it's new in the latest C++ standard so you could try `&data[0]` instead: `ConstructPacket(&data[0], data.size(), opcode);` Or if you have the `data` member function `ConstructPacket(data.data(), data.size(), opcode);`.